# Trigger SCREEN_ON event android through a background Service

Tags: android, android-service

How can I make `SCREEN_ON` event if my phone is in `SCREEN_OFF`.
Or in other words, how can I create some intent so that it invokes my phones screen from off to on.

Actually I have a service which creates a view over the top of lock screen.
In order to test it, I want to create a timer which invokes screen every 1 minute if screen is off. The service runs in background infinitely.

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this:
  private void screenOn() {
        try {
            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            boolean isScreenOn;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
                isScreenOn = pm.isInteractive();
            }
            else {
                isScreenOn = pm.isScreenOn();
            }
            if(!isScreenOn){
                KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
                KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock kl = km .newKeyguardLock("MyKeyguardLock");
                kl.disableKeyguard();

                PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE,"MyLock");
                wl.acquire(10000);
//                PowerManager.WakeLock wl_cpu = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,"MyCpuLock");
//                wl_cpu.acquire(10000);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: call this function from wherever you need in your service

Comment: It makes screen on when screen is off i am calling this function in service as well.

Comment: Most of the functions are deprecated. I tried but but my device do not wake up, if its screen off.